# Primefaces datatable export to excel won't work for huge data

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, export-to-excel

I have a small poc application made of primefaces and DerbyDB. I have 80000 records with 4 columns in the derby DB which will be reflected in the Prime faces Datatable. I added the export to excel feature for the datatable with poi jar. Now when i click the export to excel it works fine till 55000(+-1000) Records and when it crosses that i get a heap memory

> Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.iterator(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:452)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:157)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I use primefaces 3.4.2 and also tried lazy loading which doesn't solve the issue either. Please advice.

Comment: Using p:dataExporter ? Have you tried any new PF version?

Comment: This is clearly a memory issue! you should expand your virtual machine memory or your application's server.

Comment: Problem is your application server's virtual machine is too small, you need to add memory.

Comment: yes using P:DataExporter and the latest PF version also has this problem.

Comment: @Deepak what is `java heap` size of your system?